# When we update any mac application, then it reset the NSUserDefault vales or not

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsuserdefaults

I just want to make sure ,when we upload a new version of the mac application on the Mac Store, it will be enable to read the previous values of the user defaults which was stored via previous version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data should not be deleted after an update, unless the user deletes the app first.